# jQuery conflict between jPanelMenu and TweenMax/superscrollorama

Tags: javascript, conflict, jquery, gsap

I'm trying to use two(three if consider that the second uses 2 files) different plugins, jPanelMenu.js(to do a google mobile-like menu) and Superscrollorama.js(wich works together TweenMax.js), unfortunately they are conflicting, both works fine when alone, but when I put them both on the page, it all crashes. I already tried to use $.noConflict(); and jQuery.noConflict(); in a lot of different ways, unsucesfully. The best I managed to do is to make scrollorama/tweenmax work.. But, jPanelMenu still crashes.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/jquery.jpanelmenu.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery.noConflict();

         $(document).ready(function () {
            var jPM = $.jPanelMenu({
                menu: '#menu',
                trigger: '.menu-trigger',
                easing: 'ease',
                duration: 250
            });
            jPM.close(true);
            jPM.on();
            jPM.trigger(onClick);
        });

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/jquery.superscrollorama.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var controller = jQuery.superscrollorama({
            playoutAnimations: true
        });
        controller.triggerCheckAnim();
        controller.addTween('.scroll-trigger',

        (new TimelineLite())
                .append([
                  // Scale Logo
                    TweenMax.fromTo(jQuery('#logo'), 1, 
                    {css:{width: '100%', padding:'15px 0 0 0'}, ease:Strong.easeInOut, immediateRender:true}, 
                    {css:{width: '59%', padding:'5px 0 0 0'}, ease:Strong.easeInOut})
                ]),0,0);

      });
</script>
```

I'll really really really appreciate if someone here could help me with that..

Comment: Are `jpanelmenu` and `superscrollorama` jQuery plugins? If they are, I doubt they would cause a conflict. Why are you saying that you have a conflict? Wich errors do you get?

Comment: Well I guess they are jQuery, once no one works without it.. I belive it's a conflict because both don't work together, if I delete the code of first, the second works, and vice-versa.. The console returns me that $ is not defined..

Comment: When jPanelMenu stops to work, console returns me  
onClick is not defined
jPM.trigger(onClick);

Comment: Well, the `onClick` function doesn't seem to be defined anywhere in your code, so that's normal in that case... what are you trying to achieve with that line?

Comment: It must be the menu trigger, the funny thing is that when I delete all scrollorama and tweenmax, that onclick works like a charm.. but, now that you tell it, maybe I should try to use 'true', or another thing inside it.. the official documentation was too summarized form me

Comment: I checked the docs and `trigger` takes a `boolean` value as argument that will specify to animate or not when opening/closing the menu. It should be called as `trigger(true)` or `trigger(false)`.

Comment: Yep, now both plugins works together, great! But jpanel menu ALWAYS load opened.. have an idead how could I load the page with it closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the additionnal details that you gave me. Your problem is not a conflict between jQuery and others, but simply that the `onClick` function was not defined. The `trigger` function open or closes the menu depending on it's state and takes a `boolean` argument that specifies if the action will be animated or not.

If you do not want the menu to open when the page load, simply remove the `jPM.trigger(...);` call.

Comment: Omg man, sometimes I think I'm stupid.. How could I let that pass? Thank you very much, now I can sleep in peace, 4am here.. Thankyou again, how could I rate your help?

Comment: @Strobel, It happens sometimes =P Hum, you can mark the answer as accepted and upvote the answer ;) Thanks!

Comment: Oh, right in my eyes, again.. Done. But can't upvote, no reputation enough.